# Obj-c - How to convert NSMutableArray of strings into NSMutableDictionary while combining 'like' Keys and summing their Object values

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

*I am self-taught objective-c, practising and trying to learn using online courses and stack overflow. However I have hit an impasse:*

This array is generated by a user input submission (picking a day and providing a value). I'm currently taking these from user-defaults - Values provided are dynamic and these are examples:

```
NSMutableArray * arrayData;
arrayData = (NSMutableArray *) [[defaults objectForKey:@"uploadInputs"]mutableCopy];
    // Here is an example of arrayData         
    arrayData = "10/09/2017,05","12/09/2017,24","13/09/2017,05","13/09/2017,07","13/09/2017,02"
```

I want to turn this into a dictionary with date as the key and the value for the object. When there is a like key I want to sum the values in the object. So desired output would be:

```
{
    "10/09/2017" = 05;
    "12/09/2017" = 24;
    "13/09/2017" = 14;
}
```

However what I currently get is:

```
{
  "10/09/2017" =     (
    05
);
  "12/09/2017" =     (
    24
);
  "13/09/2017" =     (
    05,
    07,
    02
);

}
```

What I have done:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dictTest3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *item in arrayData) {

        NSString *key = [[item componentsSeparatedByString:@","] firstObject];
        if(!dictTest3[key]){
           dictTest3[key] = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
        [dictTest3[key] addObject:[[item componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject]];
    }
NSLog(@"dictTest3: %@ ",dictTest3);
```

**I've attempted to follow some steps provided by CRD** and simplified the code - What I'm struggling with at the moment is now summing the NSMutableArray created for having the same key.

Can I target the NSMutableArray within the dictionary?
Is something like this a thing?

```
NSMutableArray *fuBar = ;
        NSInteger sum = 0;
        for (NSNumber *num in fuBar)
        {
            sum += [num intValue];
        }
```

Comment: 05 is not an integer how you will sum anyway?

Comment: I was planning to handle this by converting it to an int with [x intValue]. I guess i'm getting ahead of my self even, combing the like objects in for keys so "13/09/2017" = 05,07,02;

Comment: I would do it in one iteration adding it directly into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayData = @[@"10/09/2017,05",
                       @"12/09/2017,24",
                       @"13/09/2017,05",
                       @"13/09/2017,07",
                       @"13/09/2017,02"];

NSMutableDictionary *finalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *aString in arrayData)
{
    NSArray *components = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *key = components[0]; //That's the date String

    NSNumber *number; //Number to set as value in the finalDict

    //We check before hand if there is already an entry
    number = [finalDict objectForKey:key];

    //Small trick: If there was no entry, then number is nil, and [number integerValue] gives 0 so after the execution number will be equals to components[1] converted into a NSNumber object. If not, it's simply added
    number = @([number integerValue] + [components[1] integerValue]);

    [finalDict setObject:number forKey:key];
}

NSLog(@"finalDict: %@", finalDict);
```

Output:

```
$> finalDict: {
    "10/09/2017" = 5;
    "12/09/2017" = 24;
    "13/09/2017" = 14;
}
```

Note, as @CRD, I thought too of `NSNumber` instead of `NSString` for the values. Seems more instinctive. 
I made a similar logic as he thought, it's more or less the concrete execution of its directives.

Comment: Thank you! This has worked, my obj-c is not as elegant / simplified as yours and the explanations certainly aided in understanding. hopefully i can upvote when I get some points

Answer (score 1):

Your code so far iterates twice over your array, splits each item twice, and discards the part (date/key, number/value) it is not interested in in this iteration, creating two intermediate arrays. These arrays are then combined into a dictionary.

Your first simple step is to iterate just once, split each item into the key & value, and add them to the dictionary immediately. This means each item is split just once, and no intermediate arrays are required.

It also helps you solve your remaining problem of how to handle repeated keys. If you look up a key in a dictionary and there is no corresponding value then `nil` is returned, using this you can easily combine your values. To produce your dictionary with `NSString` or `NSDate` objects as keys and `NSNumber` objects as values:

1. Split each item into its two parts
2. Parse the value (second) part as an integer
3. Optionally parse the key (first) part as a date or keep it as a string
4. Lookup the key in the dictionary
5. If the key value does not exist add your new key/value pair, wrapping your integer value as an `NSNumber` object so it can be stored in the dictionary
6. If the key does exist take its matching `NSNumber` object, unwrap to an integer, add your new value to it, wrap the sum as a new `NSNumber` object and add your new key/value pair to your dictionary - this replaces the existing key/value pair in the dictionary.

HTH